# Bigquery CLI commands with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, google-bigquery, command-line-interface

I can run a BigQuery script interactively just fine:

[image]

But when i try with Jenkins on the same windows machine it fails:
[image]

Do i need to install BigQuery SDK on the Jenkins Localhost, or tinker with some PATH varibles? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the directory the `bq` executable is installed has been added to your PATH variable (that would be the `PATH_TO/google-cloud-sdk/bin` directory). But this is most definitely already true given that you're able to run commands from the C drive. Different users get different permissions, so also make sure the `bq` command is available for the users Jenkins is operating under .

I've had the same issue where I couldn't run `bq` commands  using `systemctl` on linux. To go around this error, instead of running the command with `bq`, use the full path to the executable `PATH_TO/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bq`.

Comment: Actually it was the PATH variable that it needed to define in Jenkins: "manage jenkins" --> "configure system" --> "environment variables".

Comment: Ended up with following this guide: http://antagonisticpleiotropy.blogspot.com/2012/08/running-jenkins-in-windows-with-regular.html